# InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

I'm very new to python, trying to create reusable code. when I try to call the class Login and function login_user in test_main.py by passing all the arguments that were used under Login class, I'm getting an error as InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string.

test_main.py file which runs on pytest.

Locators_test is the class of test_Locators.py file where I have all my xpaths

test_main.py

```
def test_setup():

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= Locators_test.browser_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get(homePage)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
yield
print("test complete")
```

test_Locators.py

```
class Locators_test():

loginlink_xpath = "//a[@id='login-link']"
login_email = "xxxxx"
login_password = "xxxxx"
loginemail_id = "dnn_ctr1179_Login_txtEmail"
loginpassword_id = "dnn_ctr1179_Login_txtPassword"
clicklogin_id = "dnn_ctr1179_Login_btnLogin"
```

test_login.py

```
from Smoketest.locatorfile.test_Locators import Locators_test

class Login():

def __init__(self,driver):

    self.driver = driver

def login_user(self,driver):
    try:
        loginButton = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, Locators_test.loginlink_xpath))
        while loginButton.click() is True:
            break
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300);")

        EmailField = self.driver.find_element((By.ID, Locators_test.loginemail_id))
        EmailField.send_keys(Locators_test.login_email)

        PasswordField = self.driver.find_element((By.ID, Locators_test.loginpassword_id))
        PasswordField.send_keys(Locators_test.login_password)

        ClickLogin = self.driver.find_element((By.ID, Locators_test.clicklogin_id))
        while ClickLogin.click() is True:
            break

        time.sleep(5)

        userName = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, Locators_test.username_xpath))
        print("Logged in as", userName.text)



    except StaleElementReferenceException or ElementClickInterceptedException or TimeoutException as ex:
        print(ex.message)
```

test_main.py

```
def test_login(test_setup):

from Smoketest.pages.test_login import Login

lo = Login(driver)
lo.login_user(((Locators_test.loginlink_xpath,Locators_test.loginemail_id,Locators_test.login_email,Locators_test.loginpassword_id,Locators_test.login_password,Locators_test.clicklogin_id,Locators_test.username_xpath)))
```

Comment: Welcome. This line: `lo = Login(driver)`, where do you get the variable `driver`? Your example doesn't show that. The last line in `test_main.py`, you're calling the function `login_user()` with several parameters, but look at your definition in `Login` class... there's only `def login_user(self,driver):`, that won't work well.

Comment: Your code doesn't even mention  "using". I guess you've forgotten some part of it.

Comment: @pavelsaman Hi, I have initiated self.driver in test_login.py in __init__ method and calling it in test_main.py

Comment: @JoãoFarias Hi, I have not used 'using' anywhere in my code i have no idea where it comes from

Comment: @Mohan: no, you didn't. if the code you're showing us is everything, `driver` is not defined on this line `lo = Login(driver)` in `test_main.py`. And you need to pay attention to the arguments you're passing to `login_user()` on the next line.

Comment: @pavelsaman in test_main.py i have a setup method in which I have initiated driver and inheriting test_setup in test_login in test_main.py

Comment: @Mohan: then show us the whole code. Because what you're saying is not what I read in your code in the question.

Comment: @pavelsaman I have added test_setup in the question, please check

Comment: what is there in homepage variable?

Comment: @PDHide site's URL

Comment: @Mohan does it have any string in it ?

Comment: @PDHide no it doesn't(i mean the value of homepage ofc a string as eg:"https://google.com"), I didn't get any error on that part.Error arises only when it starts to execute test_login in test_main.py when i pass more than one arguments to lo.login_user otherwise it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself by removing the extra pair of parenthesis from the line

`loginButton = self.driver.find_element((By.XPATH, Locators_test.loginlink_xpath))`.

Right way is

`loginButton = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, Locators_test.loginlink_xpath)`

ps: this applies to all the lines.